# PDO Custom Error From rowCount Statement Query After Conversion From Mysql

Tags: php, pdo

I previously had an SQL query and statement which had a row affected count at the end and would check to see if a row had been changed. If the thing being inserted already existed it would show a blank page saying a plain and simple `This user already exists` with a `a href` back to the form. I converted the entire solution over to `PDO` which works perfectly but the page no longer shows instead i get the full `PDO error throw` even though i am echoing the code which i assume should override it. How do i make my own error show instead? or page.

```
if ($statement->rowCount($link) ==  0){
    echo "No rows affected! User exists already? <br/>";
    echo "<a href='../index'>Back to admin page</a>";
} else{
    echo "{$name} Added! Date: {$date} <br>";
    echo "<a href='../index.php'>Back to admin page</a><br/>";
}
```

Comment: [You have to catch PDO exception](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#catch)

Comment: I tried catching and it gave me an error.

Comment: Fixed it now, i realized what i did wrong.